# Set HTML image src to form input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I would like an image to be displayed based on what is entered inside the form. The problem is with `figure_id` as when displayed with console log it is a blank string even when text is submitted inside the form.

```
<form  method="GET" id="figure_choice_form">
    <label for="figure_id">Enter ID</label>
    <input type="text" id="figure_id" name="figure_id">
</form>

<img id="figure_image" src="RESULT_FROM_THE_FUNCTION" alt="img">
```

JavaScript I have tried

```
<script>
    function set_image_path(){
    var figure_id = document.getElementById("figure_id").value
    var image_path = `main/Bricklink/images/${figure_id}.png`
    document.getElementById("figure_image").img.src = image_path
    }
    set_image_path()
</script>
```

Comment: Typo error in your function set_image_path, `.img.**scr**` is incorrect, change it to `.img.src`

Comment: also need to add an event to the input, or a button to fire the function, firing it onload the value wont be filled

Comment: The problem seems to be with figure_id. When i console log it, it is a blank string, therefore image_path is "main/Bricklink/images/.png"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here `document.getElementById("figure_image").img.src`, there is no `img` property.

So change it to `document.getElementById("figure_image").src`

```js
function set_image_path() {
  const figure_id = document.getElementById("figure_id");
  const figure_image = document.getElementById("figure_image");
  const image_path = `main/Bricklink/images/${figure_id.value}.png`;
  figure_image.src = image_path;
  console.log(figure_image.src);
}

//call function in submit listener
const form_figure = document.getElementById("figure_choice_form");
form_figure.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  set_image_path();
})

//call function in load page - if input has value
set_image_path();
```

```html
<form method="GET" id="figure_choice_form">
  <label for="figure_id">Enter ID</label>
  <input type="text" id="figure_id" name="figure_id" value="image123">
  <button> Submit </button>
</form>

<img id="figure_image" src="RESULT_FROM_THE_FUNCTION" alt="img">
```